# OpenLDAP: Invalid syntax error when trying to add LDIF

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I keep getting an invalid syntax error when trying to create a user in OpenLDAP (CentOS 7).

This is a new install of OpenLDAP for testing purposes.

So far I've managed to create a group called "Lab Staff", and now I'm trying to add a user to it

Here is the LDIF file:

```
dn: uid=lsuarez,ou=Lab Staff,dc=sftest,dc=net
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Luis Suarez
sn: Suarez
givenname: Luis
uid: lsuarez
ou: Lab Staff
```

Then I try to add it as follows:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Admin,dc=sftest,dc=net" -W  -f /tmp/data.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "uid=lsuarez,ou=Lab Staff,dc=sftest,dc=net"
```

I get the error message:

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
        additional info: objectclass: value #3 invalid per syntax
```

That looks to me like it doesn't like `inetOrgPerson`, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the schema for `inetOrgPerson` into `slapd`.

I have no idea about OpenLDAP installation on CentOS 7, but if you have a file `/etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif` and dynamic slapd configuration (`/etc/ldap/slapd.d/`), it might accept the following command (run as root).

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```

Comment: Thanks you were essentially correct, but my whole installation was wrong from the outset. This guide I found is the correct one and invaluable!

http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-ldap-directory-service-user-connection/

Answer (score 0):

**To fix the problem please run the below commands:**

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.ldif 


ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif


ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.ldif
```